# html output from stored procedure in a variable in servlets getting truncated

Tags: servlets

i am having a stored procedure in sql server which returns a variable of nvarchar(max) datatype . the value of the variable is a html file contains table.
in servlets i am able to get the output value from the stored procedure and store it in a string variable. But when i am printing it then it is getting truncated and some portion of the html file is missing. how to overcome this issue.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to be more clear about the problem. What exactly happens? What exactly happens not? What is been truncated? What is that portion? Give the smallest possible examples which reproduces the problem.

Comment: ok my sp generates a html file as an out parameter value, i am capturing the out param in a string. i am able to see the entire html file in the sql server 2k5, but when it is stored in a string in servlet the lat few portions are truncated and only a part of file is displaying. hope i am clear

Comment: String output="";
try{
cstmt.execute();
output=cstmt.getString(3);
 }

this is a portion of my code in servlet which captures the out param value.
the datatype of the out param value in sp is nvarchar(max)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as for this is concerned i find out the reason, i was using wrong jdbc sql data type , while i was using varchar it is truncating but when i changed that into longvarchar then things got working now.